# Regex - How can I get different string in the same line from a log file?

Tags: c#, regex, text-files

I'm looking for some assistance to get specific strings from text file.
The text file has specifics words that I'm using for get the result that I'm looking for.

**Here's the log example:**

> TLWin Session Data Log - TaskLink Version 7.90    Date Logged: 
>   09-29-2014 02:17:45 PM  Task Name:  XXXXXX_A06_U1  User ID: 
>   Administrator Mode  System:   PP/PS Series FlashCORE  Machine ID: 
>   123456789    Device:   WINBOND_ELECTRONICS W25Q64FV-SS-Q SO8  Data
>   Source:  c:\xptox_projects\xxxxx\xxxxxxxx(8mb).bin  Sumcheck: 
>   12345678  Process:  Continuity/Blank Check/ID
>   Check/Erase/Program/Verify/Mark/Vision  Process Status:  Job Begin
>   Status: New Job, Job End Status: Stopped  TLWin Session ID: < none >
>   Job Start Time:  09-29-2014 10:23:37 AM  Job End Time:  09-29-2014
>   02:17:45 PM  Devices Total:  1105  Devices Passed:  1104  Devices
>   Failed:  1  Overall Device Yield: 99.91%    Task Description:
>   W25Q64FVS    Nominal Throughput: 666 dph  Job Throughput:  290 dph 
>   Devices Picked Input: 1110  Devices Failed Vision: 0  Devices Failed
>   REST: 0  Devices Missing/In Use: 5    Job Elapsed Time: 3 Hours 0
>   Minutes 54 Seconds  Job Setup Time:  0 Hours 0 Minutes 5 Seconds  Job
>   Processing Time: 1 Hours 0 Minutes 40 Seconds  Job Assistance Time: 2
>   Hours 0 Minutes 8 Seconds  Job Shutdown Time: 0 Hours 0 Minutes 0
>   Seconds    Algorithm:  3605410C.ELF  Algorithm Status: Beta  Algorithm
>   Author: Data I/O  Alg COM Dll:  < not used >  Alg COM Dll Version: <
>   not used >    TaskLink Version: 7.90  AH500 Version:  6.5.0  Firmware
>   Version: 05.52.00.C  Serialization Program: < not used > 
>   Serialization Prog Ver: < not used >    Input Media:  Tape  Output
>   Media:  Tape  Reject 1:  Tray 1  Reject 2:  n/a    Starting Serial
>   Number: N.A.  Ending Serial Number: N.A.  Unused Serial Numbers: N.A. 
>   Category: PASS, CF, NB, IB, PF,VF1,VF2,FT1,FT2,SFF,SFB, DO, EF,EID, OE
>   TotalStats: 1104,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 
>   0  Site 1 Skt 1:    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
>   0,  0  Site 1 Skt 2:    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
>   0,  0,  0  Site 1 Skt 3:    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
>   0,  0,  0,  0  Site 1 Skt 4:    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
>   0,  0,  0,  0,  0  Site 2 Skt 1:    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
>   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0  Site 2 Skt 2:    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
>   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0  Site 2 Skt 3:    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
>   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0  Site 2 Skt 4:    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
>   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0  Site 3 Skt 1:  139,  0,  0,  0,  0,
>   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0  Site 3 Skt 2:  139,  0,  0,  0,
>   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0  Site 3 Skt 3:  138,  0,  0,
>   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0  Site 3 Skt 4:  135,  1,
>   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0  Site 4 Skt 1:  141,
>   0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0  Site 4 Skt 2: 
>   138,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0  Site 4
>   Skt 3:  137,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0 
>   Site 4 Skt 4:  137,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
>
> ### 0,  0

Here's the specify data that I need to collect and store in somewhere:

```
Date Logged:  09-29-2014
Task Name:  XXXXXX_A06_U1
Machine ID: 123456789
Device: WINBOND_ELECTRONICS W25Q64FV-SS-Q SO8
Devices Total: 1105
Devices Passed: 1104
Devices Failed: 1
Overall Device Yield: 99.91%
Nominal Throughput: 666
Job Throughput: 290
Devices Picked Input: 1110
Devices Failed Vision: 0
Devices Failed REST: 0
```

The results that I wanna to store are after the ":". The results will be send to DB through SQL procedure (next step).

Here's the code:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Path"], "*.log"))
            {

                Regex found = new Regex(@"Date\sLogged\s*:\s*([\d\-]+).*\nTask\sName\s*:\s*(.+)[\n]|.*Machine\sID\s*:\s*(\d+)[\n]|.*Device\s*:\s*(.+)");
                string fileText = File.ReadAllText(file);
                string fileTextReplacement = Regex.Replace(fileText, @"\t|\n|\r"," ");

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileText))
                {

                    if (found.Match(fileText).Success)
                    {

                        DateTime dtLogged = Convert.ToDateTime(found.Match(fileText).Groups[1].Value);
                        string taskName = found.Match(fileText).Groups[2].Value;
                        string machineId = found.Match(fileText).Groups[3].Value;
                        string icDevice = found.Match(fileText).Groups[4].Value;
                        int deviceTotal = Convert.ToInt32(found.Match(fileText).Groups[5].Value);
                        int devicePassed = Convert.ToInt32(found.Match(fileText).Groups[6].Value);

                    }

                }
```

Any help will be very appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Are these on separate lines ? or is it jumbled as what we see in your post

Comment: These information are like my post (little mess). That's the result of string "fileTextReplacement". @MichaelRandall

Comment: Is it always in this order?

Comment: Yes, the order it's the same as above and will not change due the file log template :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you need is essentially

```
(<start>)(.*)(?=<finish>)|(<start>)(.*)(?=<finish>) ... ect...
```

It can be simply read as

- `(Date Logged:)` Start at `"Date Logged:"`
- `(.*)` match everything in between
- `(?=Task Name:)` End at `"Task Name:"`

So the next step is to just build up the pattern

```
// these need to be in order as seen in the log file
var tags = new List<string>() 
               {
                  "Date Logged:",
                  "Task Name:",
                  "User ID:",
                  "System:",
                  "Machine ID:",
                  "Device:",
                  "Data Source"
               };

var sb = new StringBuilder();

// Create a pattern
for (var index = 1; index < tags.Count; index++)
{
   // all this is doing building up your matching patern
   // as described above
   sb.Append($"({tags[index - 1]})(.*)(?={tags[index]})");

   // dont put the OR on the end
   if (index < tags.Count - 1) sb.Append("|");
}

// some input
var input = @"TLWin Session Data Log - TaskLink Version 7.90 Date Logged: 09-29-2014 02:17:45 PM Task Name: XXXXXX_A06_U1 User ID: Administrator Mode System: PP/PS Series FlashCORE Machine ID: 123456789 Device: WINBOND_ELECTRONICS W25Q64FV-SS-Q SO8 Data Source: c:\xptox_projects\xxxxx\xxxxxxxx(8mb).bin Sumcheck: 12345678 Process: Continuity/Blank Check/ID Check/Erase/Program/Verify/Mark/Vision Process Status: Job Begin Status: New Job, Job End Status: Stopped TLWin Session ID: < none >
Job Start Time: 09-29-2014 10:23:37 AM Job End Time: 09-29-2014 02:17:45 PM Devices Total: 1105 Devices Passed: 1104 Devices Failed: 1 Overall Device Yield: 99.91% Task Description: W25Q64FVS Nominal Throughput: 666 dph Job Throughput: 290 dph Devices Picked Input: ";

// do some matching
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, sb.ToString());
foreach (var match in matches)
{
   Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

[**You can see the demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZukTV9)

The only caveat is it expects all the log descriptors (and in order). If this isn't the case, then you will have to modify this to search every for ever start, and every possible end and put it in a loop. which shouldn't be too difficult

```
(Date Logged:)(.*?)(?=(Task Name:|User ID:|System:|ect...))
```

Comment: Thanks bro! Works fine!